# Cannot resolve SupportFragmentManager in MvxFramentActivity

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Following along in the N=26 presentation for fragments, I am running into a problem where the SupportFragmentManager is not able to be resolved:
[image: Cannot resolve symbol 'SupportFragmentManager']
I have MVVMCross and all dependencies (3.5.0), MVVMCross fragment support (3.5.0), and Xamarin Support Library v4 (21.0.3.0) added from NuGet with the references showing up properly in the project.

I also find the same issues with the project at https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/b405eef7dddf4d65b00116e142855653eae9f06b/N-26-Fraggle

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: try inheriting from `AppCompatActivity` instead of `MvxFragmentActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your target API level and minimum API level are lower than 14. If yes, probably you will need to use Support V4:

using FragmentManager = Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager;

I hope you will solve.

Comment: That is correct. It should be automatically resolving to FragmentActivity.SupportFragmentManager in Android.Support.v4.App.FragmentManger since MvxFragmentActivity inherits from FragmentActivity in Android.Support.V4.App.

I don't get it, but I opened up the solution today and without making any changes what-so-ever it's resolving properly. I also opened up the sample NPlus1 sample project I was having trouble with and it's working too.

Comment: The Chimps have changed things overnight ...